# USB 3.0 memory stick fails with "SEL for device-initiated U2 failed"

Tags: usb, kernel, dmesg, lsusb

This is a Kingston Data Traveler Ultimate G3 memory stick. Device works fine on Windows (same hardware), but it doesn't show up in lsusb on an Ubtuntu 16.10 with Kernel 4.4.0.

dmesg shows the problem:

```
dmesg | grep -i usb

[63864.126086] usb 2-3.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
[63864.156440] usb 2-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1697
[63864.156445] usb 2-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[63864.156447] usb 2-3.1: Product: DT Ultimate G3
[63864.156449] usb 2-3.1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[63864.156451] usb 2-3.1: SerialNumber: -redacted-
[63869.157678] usb 2-3.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[63869.157771] usb-storage 2-3.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[63869.158411] scsi host38: usb-storage 2-3.1:1.0
[63869.159752] usb 2-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 39
```

If I leave the device connected it will infinitly loop recognizing the device then failing settig SEL for device-initiated U2 and disconnecting the device, then reconnecting, failing again and so on.

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very weird, but try inserting flash drive very slowly into the port. Helped for me.
Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1295579

Comment: Oddly enough that fixed my problem (I also tried another USB port so maybe that?)